# Mails not working in Yii Using Xampp

Tags: php, email, yii, phpmailer

I'm building an API and on the aspect of sending a mail. I'm getting mail not sent error. In my API, the front-end sends a JSON request consisting of the mail parameters.

```
{
    "to":"gideonappoh@gmail.com",
    "subject":"Testing Reviewer's Page",
    "body": "Hello Gideon",
    "headers":"oksana.v@scopicsoftware.com"
}
```

I then decode them and pass them through a PHPMail method in my controller. But its not working, and I can't find whats wrong. Can someone help me. These are my codes.

```
    public function actionSendMail() {
    //Getting request from frontend
    $request = file_get_contents('php://input');

    //Decoding input into an array
    $input = json_decode($request, true);

    //Validating request
    if (is_null($input)) {
        $response = json_encode(['error' => 'Bad Input']);
        die($response);

    } else {
        //mail parameters
        $to      = $input['to'];
        $subject = $input['subject'];
        $body    = $input['body'];
        $headers = $input['headers'];

        //Sending mail 
        if($result = $this->sendMail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
            $response = json_encode(['success' => true]);
            echo $response;
        } else {
            $response = json_encode(['error' => 'Mail Not Sent']);
            die($response);
        }
    }
}

private function sendMail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers) {
    //Configurating PHP Mailer
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->Host = 'stmp.emailsrvr.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'gideon.a@scopicsoftware.com';
    $mail->Password = 'n010grc7dsx';
    $mail->Mailer = 'stmp';
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->Port = 25;

    //Sending mail
    $mail->SetFrom($headers);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->MsgHTML($body);
    $mail->AddAddress($to);

    if(!$mail->Send())
        return $mail->ErrorInfo;

    return true;
}
```

I have read many articles on configuring xampp and I think I should work but still not working. Always getting the response `{ "error":"Mail not sent" }`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;` to see what's going on.

Comment: At first it prompted could not instantiate mail function

Comment: I'm editing my answer with the new codes